# Extracting dataframe columns for mapped data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, artificial-intelligence

**Background**:
Excel sheet with mapping. General appearance like this:

```
                Req1     Req2     Req3 ..... Req10
                A  B     A  B     A  B       A   B
Id     Text      
1      abc         x     x                       x
2      def               x
3      ghi                  x
4      jkl                                       x
5      mno      x
```

Edit: [Screenshot of Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j5p2.png)

**Question**: How to extract only the columns with the marked 'x'? That is, Column Req3 would not be considered.

**Challenge**: Column headers are merged cells in the original excel - and at a different level than the "Text" column.

**Already Tried**: Looking into .groupby() function and for loops. But not sure how to proceed with either options (if they are applicable).

IDEA: (update) Splitting the file into two separate dataframes (Text + Reqs). Deleting the rows that cause the difference between the placing of the headers. Then rejoining the separate dataframes ---- But how?

Already have the entire excel file converted to .csv and opened as dataframe in jupyternotebooks code. Can also extract separate columns, but because of the difference between the column titles, cannot get "ReqN" to be part of dataframe.

**Expected Result**: Pandas dataframe with column "Text" and the column "ReqN" where the "x" occurs. (Not interested in whether it is A or B that is marked.)

**Next Step**: (in case relevant for solution above) to store the "Text"+ corresponding "ReqN" somehow as a csv file.

Newbie to python and pandas. Would really appreciate some guidance for the code. Found several examples on SO, but they fell short somewhere or the other.

Comment: Are you able to show exactly what the sheet looks like in Excel, maybe an image? Are `A`, `B`, etc in separate columns, but just the `Req1`, `Req2` in one large merged cell?

Comment: @Tom, yes exactly. Managed to add a link to the screenshot in post.

Comment: Could you also post what you get when you try to import the data i.e. `pd.read_csv()` or similar?

Comment: Didn't mean to suggest that there were errors, what I meant was to post, say, `df.head()` just so it's easier to see what your working with.

Comment: @Tom, thank you for pitching in. Unfortunately the data is not mine to post on a public forum. I however managed to find a different approach for the solution. Answer as below. Seems to do the job for now at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was hoping to reduce the size of my .csv file by cutting down the unnecessary data before entering it into the code. However for my files I found that the memory or the speed would not be an issue. And since the cutting beforehand approach was giving me too many errors, I tried a different method.

Solved this furthering on the "idea" described in the question. Posting code with details below. It is perhaps a longer approach, but for a novice like me, it solves the job.

```
#IMPORTING NECESSARY LIBRARIES
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

#TO CONVERT EXCEL TO .CSV
def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"\...\Data Docs\DATA_FILE.xlsm")
    ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Index')
    csv_train_data_1 = open('csv_train_data_1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    wr = csv.writer(csv_train_data_1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(ws.nrows):
        wr.writerow(ws.row_values(rownum))

    csv_train_data_1.close()

csv_from_excel()

#PLAN TO USE maxRows LATER
fileName = r"\...\Data Docs\DATA_FILE.xlsm"
wb2 = load_workbook(fileName)
ws4 = wb2["Index"]
maxRows = ws4.max_row
print(maxRows)

#CONVERTS CSV TO DATAFRAME
df = pd.read_csv("csv_train_data_1.csv") 

#CREATES NEW DF WITH UNNECESSARY ROWS REMOVED
df = pd.read_csv("csv_train_data_1.csv", header = 1)
df2 = df.drop([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

#CUTS, AND MERGES SECTIONS OF DATAFRAME TO WHAT I NEEDED
cols = [1]
useful_df_1 = df[df.columns[cols]]
useful_df_2 = df[df2.columns[25:73]] 
useful_df_3 = useful_df_1.join([useful_df_2])
useful_df = useful_df_3.drop([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

# RENAMING OF ONE COLUMN
result_new = useful_df.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 1": "Specification no."})

#REPLACES ALL NaN VALUES WITH EMPTY/BLANK STRING FOR CLEANER DATA
import numpy as np
result_clean= result_new.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
result_clean.head(maxRows)
```

And finally

```
#TO EXPORT THE FILE AS .CSV TO LOCAL FOLDER
export_csv = result_clean.to_csv(r'\...\Data\export_dataframe.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

[image: This was the final result.]

This was the final result. The *Unnamed (n)* columns are the `B` columns from the example data in the question. Apparently the columns with the titles included the `A` columns.

The data I had was quite large, several hundred columns and rows. By default pandas dataframe has a set value of rows and columns in the window it shows. To alter these values to fit your dataset, the following code can be used:

```
import pandas as pd

def start():
    options = {
        'display': {
            'max_columns': None,
            'max_colwidth': 25,
            'expand_frame_repr': False,  # Don't wrap to multiple pages
            'max_rows': 85,
            'max_seq_items': 50,         # Max length of printed sequence
            'precision': 4,
            'show_dimensions': False
        },
        'mode': {
            'chained_assignment': None   # Controls SettingWithCopyWarning
        }
    }

    for category, option in options.items():
        for op, value in option.items():
            pd.set_option(f'{category}.{op}', value)  # Python 3.6+

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
    del start  # Clean up namespace in the interpreter
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for the solution. 
The data isn't mine to post on a public forum, hence I apologize for not being able to share more details.